# Operator reference in JAVA

Tags: java, c#, selenium

I'm finding it hard to identify the operator which will replace the return statement, whereby I'll just have to pass the operator itself and ignore the return statement.

I have worked in C#, For the same code,

```
public IWebelement usernameFiled() 
{
    driver.FindElement(By.id("gbqfq");
    return usernameFiled; 
}
```

Can also be written as,

```
 public IWebelement usernameFiled() => driver.FindElement(By.id("gbqfq");
```

I'm just starting in Java and I'm trying to find its equivalent operator to C#'s "follows" operator (`=>`).

Any ideas, please!

Comment: There is not, it's easy ;) So normal that's you look hard for ;)

Comment: `public IWebelement usernameFiled() { return driver.FindElement(By.id("gbqfq"); }`. More verbose, but not really meaningfully so.

Comment: See if this helps https://www.javatpoint.com/java-lambda-expressions ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check lambda expressions / method references and functional interfaces in Java 8. It's not fully identical to what you've specified, but pretty close. You can write lambdas (anonymous functions) without `return` statement. Simple example:

```
private WebElement waitFor(By locator, Function<By, ExpectedCondition<WebElement>> condition) {
    return wait.until(condition.apply(locator));
}
```

Second argument could be passed as a lambda expression or method reference:

```
waitFor(locator, by -> ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(by)).click();
waitFor(locator, ExpectedConditions::elementToBeClickable).click();
```

`elementToBeClickable` is a method, which returns `ExpectedCondition<WebElement>`, but we don't need to use `return` statement explicitly.